# ReadAsStringAsync returns dashed description

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I have a method ReadJsonUrl which gets a url(string address (for the example: https://www.ah.nl/service/rest/delegate?url=%2Fproducten%2Fproduct%2Fwi224732%2Fsmiths-nibb-it-happy-ones-kruis-rond-paprika )) to a JSON file.

This method reads the JSON and outputs some of the data in the console.

But the problem is that the description from the product is outputted like

> Smiths Nibb-it hap-­py on-­es kruis-rond pa-­pri-­ka

but if I check the JSON in my browser it shows

> Smiths Nibb-it hap­py on­es kruis-rond pa­pri­ka

and that's how I want it to print.

What I think the problem is, the request is done with a 0px by 0px resolution browser so it returns the words divided to keep it readable. If I make my browser really small then it also shows the description with the dashes.
I added an user agent in my code, but that didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

My code:

```
    public static async Task<object> ReadJsonUrl(string address)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(address);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //JObject obj = JObject.Parse(content);


            var data = Empty.FromJson(content);

            var product = data.Embedded.Lanes[4].Embedded.Items[0].Embedded.Product;

            Console.WriteLine(product.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(product.Description);
            Console.WriteLine(product.PriceLabel.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(product.Availability.Label);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            //the return value is for later use
            return product;

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `Empty.FromJson()`? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: The Json request doesn't know it is coming from a 0x0 browser, so that would not affect the data. It is either an issue with `Empty.FromJson()` (as Thomas says, what is this?) or how it is being displayed from the browser (how are you doing this?). If you think it is an issue with the 0x0 browser, try calling it from a 500x500 browser and see if that has any impact

Comment: @ThomasWeller I got the Empty.FromJson() from this website: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement Thomas Weller's answer, that explains the problem very well, here is a function that will strip out all the soft hyphens from a `string`.  It is written as an extension method, so you can use it easily like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(product.Description.RemoveSoftHyphens());
```

The extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveSoftHyphens(this string input)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (c != 0xAD)
            {
                output.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

As a bit of additional information, here is HTML4's description of the use of soft hyphens:

> In HTML, there are two types of hyphens: the plain hyphen and the soft hyphen. The plain hyphen should be interpreted by a user agent as just another character. The soft hyphen tells the user agent where a line break can occur. Those browsers that interpret soft hyphens must observe the following semantics. If a line is broken at a soft hyphen, a hyphen character must be displayed at the end of the first line. If a line is not broken at a soft hyphen, the user agent must not display a hyphen character. For operations such as searching and sorting, the soft hyphen should always be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

If you copy&paste your second string (expected output) into a hex editor, it will tell you that it has `0xAD` characters. These are [soft hyphens](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ad/index.htm).

A browser like Internet Explorer or Firefox will only display those soft hyphens if necessary (at a line break), but the Console displays it every time.

[image: Screen shot of hex Editor]

Comment: I copied it into notepad++ and it displayed them as well.

Comment: So if I just post the data in a database and read it with the browser I should be fine?

Comment: @valheru: yes. Otherwise you could also filter the soft hyphens.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and will let you know when everything works out.

Comment: Just to add some extra information:  The soft hyphen is used as a hint to the browser for locations where a word can be safely broken up if the line needs to wrap.  If the word isn't broken, no hyphen will be displayed, but if it is broken, the browser will search back in the string looking for something it can break on.  It will prefer the soft hyphen within the word, break it there, and display the hyphen.